# Modify array recursively in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to modify an array in a PHP 5 function.

> Example input:

```
array('name' => 'somename', 'products' => stdClass::__set_state(array()))
```

> Expected output:

```
array('name' => 'somename', 'products' => null)
```

I have written the following code to replace empty objects (which are *stdClass::__set_state(array())* objects) with null. The method works fine (I've used some debug logs to check), but the array I'm giving it does not change.

```
private function replaceEmptyObjectsWithNull(&$argument){
    if (is_array($argument)){
        foreach ($argument as $innerArgument) {
            $this->replaceEmptyObjectsWithNull($innerArgument);
        }
    } else if (is_object($argument)){
        if (empty((array) $argument)) {
            // If object is an empty object, make it null.
            $argument = null;
            \Log::debug("Changed an empty object to null"); // Is printed many times, as expected.
            \Log::debug($argument); // Prints an empty line, as expected.
        } else {
            foreach ($argument as $innerArgument) {
                $this->replaceEmptyObjectsWithNull($innerArgument);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call this method like this:

```
$this->replaceEmptyObjectsWithNull($myArray);
\Log::debug($myArray); // myArray should be modified, but it's not.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm parsing the argument by reference, right?

Comment: Change `foreach ($argument as $innerArgument)` to `foreach ($argument as &$innerArgument)`. This way `$innerArgument` is a reference and not a copy.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed, awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do this.

You just have to change your foreach loop to reference your variables and *not* use a copy of your variables. You can do this with the ampersand symbol in front of your `$innerArgument`.

```
foreach ($argument as &$innerArgument) {
    $this->replaceEmptyObjectsWithNull($innerArgument);
}
```

Notice the `&` symbol in front of `$innerArgument` in the loop.

You can learn more about this [in the PHP docs](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). You can also learn more about references in general [in the PHP docs](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).